# `Summary` multiple LM and GLM objects

Tags: r, glm, lm

I have 50 `lm` and `glm` objects in R. I want to get the summary of all of them without having to type `summary(lm...)` 50 times. Is there a quick way to do it? The names of the dataset begin the same way: **lin.mod.t#** or **lin.mod.s#** where {# = 1,2,...,25}. I can list all the models using

```
ls(pattern = "lin.mod")
objects(pattern = "lin.mod")
```

But I cannot run `summary` for the outcomes of using `ls` or `objects`. I used `summary(eval(parse(text = ls(pattern = "lin.mod"))))`, but this only runs the first one. Any suggestions? Maybe use `lapply`?

Comment: How did you get 50 lm and glm objects in the first place? Maybe start there and also why are they not saved in a list to maintain **one** object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
# 2 sample models
lin.mod.1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars);
lin.mod.2 <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars);

# Get models and store in list
lst <- lapply(ls(pattern = "lin.mod"), get);

# Summary of models
res <- lapply(lst, summary);
```

Explanation: `get` all models that match pattern `"lin.mod"` from the current environment and store in list `lst`. Use `lapply` to store `summary` of all models in list `res`.

Answer (score 1):

You may choose **NSE** version of **BaseR** to solve this, like below,I am using two functions, `eval` and `as.name`, You may choose as.symbol instead of as.name as they both behave similarly:

```
?as.name
```

> as.name first coerces its argument internally to a character vector
>   (so methods for as.character are not used). It then takes the first
>   element and provided it is not ""returns a symbol of that name (and if the element is NA_character_, the name is `NA`).

```
?eval
```

> eval evaluates the expr argument in the environment specified by envir
>   and returns the computed value. If envir is not specified, then the
>   default is parent.frame() (the environment where the call to eval was
>   made).

```
lin.mod.1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
lin.mod.2 <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)
lin.mod.3 <- lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)

objects_lms <- ls(pattern ="lin\\.mod")
vals <- lapply(objects_lms, function(x)eval(as.name(x)))
lapply(vals, summary)
```

Comment: I see no advantage of using `eval(as.name(...))` over `get` (see my earlier solution).